# Get value of multiple child elements XML

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

Lets pretend that my XML snippet contained several more 'Result' elements. How would I approach retrieving the Name and Time of every Result? Preferably with lxml.

```
<data>
  <Results>
    <Result>
      <Name>Result1</Name>
      <Value>1</Value>
      <Time>1h</Time>
    </Result>
    <Result>
      <Name>Result2</Name>
      <Value>2</Value>
      <Time>5h</Time>
    </Result>
  </Results>
</data>
```

Comment: Please share  your current code and the issues you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
res = """your xml above"""
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.fromstring(res)
results = doc.xpath('//Results//Result')
for result in results:
    print(result.xpath('.//Name/text()'),result.xpath('.//Time/text()'))
```

Output:

```
['Result1'] ['1h']
['Result2'] ['5h']
```